# There is some WITH clause in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to do a query in database using temporary tables through WITH clause:

```sql
WITH temp (id, category, brand, model, fullname) AS (
SELECT equipment.id, categories.name, equipment.brand, equipment.model,
CONCAT(categories.name,' ',equipment.brand,' ',equipment.model) AS fullname
FROM equipment INNER JOIN categories
ON equipment.category_id = categories.id
)
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE fullname LIKE '%VALUE%' LIMIT 10
```

This was my implementation:

```php
$viewRaw = Equipment::join('categories', 'category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->select(
        'categories.name',
        'equipment.id',
        DB::raw("CONCAT(categories.name,' ',equipment.brand,' ',equipment.model) AS fullname")
    )->toSql();
$result = DB::select("WITH temp AS ($viewRaw) SELECT * FROM temp WHERE fullname LIKE '%$value%' LIMIT 10");
```

Are there some way to improve this code? Exist some clause WITH and CONCAT in Laravel Eloquent? I can't find in Documentation.

Comment: The "easy" way out here is to just inline the CTE, then write Laravel code for the resulting query.

Comment: Also note that your outer query is not well defined, as it uses `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.